# cannot install doctrine event though i have mongo driver

Tags: php, mongodb, doctrine-orm, composer-php, archlinux

I am trying to install doctrine using composer on my machine. But it fail with the following message  :

`Problem 1
    - Installation request for doctrine/mongodb 1.2.*@dev -> satisfiable by doctrine/mongodb[1.2.x-dev].
    - doctrine/mongodb 1.2.x-dev requires ext-mongo >=1.2.12,<1.7-dev -> the requested PHP extension mongo is missing from your system.`

But, i already installed mongodb driver and my php cli can loaded it.

```
php -m | grep mongo
mongo
php --ri mongo | grep Version
Version => 1.5.7
php --ini
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php/conf.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php/conf.d/apcu.ini,
/etc/php/conf.d/mongo.ini,
/etc/php/conf.d/xdebug.ini
```

Anyone can show me what I've missed ? Thanks in advance 
Oh btw i'm on linux arch 32bit.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem. The solution is to modify the php.ini file that is actually user by composer.

I found this by doing a `whereis composer` and then `file /path/of/composer`. That gave me a clue about where is actually the php.ini file that composer uses. Once I found the file, I just had to add the mongo extension in it.

Check here https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1512476#p1512476